# Multiple table join query, with count in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I'm trying to count the number of inspections of each property in YR_Inspection table by counting the number of times the property number occurs in the table, i then need to display this next to the town the city the property is located in and the branch the property belongs to all in the same query. Here is the link to my ERD to try and give this question some context,

[image]

http://www.gliffy.com/pubdoc/4239520/L.png

this is the code so far, it works so far but as soon as i add YR_Branch.CITY i get,

ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

```
SELECT YR_Property.PROPERTYNUM, COUNT(YR_Inspection.PROPERTYNUM) AS Number_of_inspections
FROM YR_Property  
INNER JOIN YR_Inspection 
    ON YR_Property.PROPERTYNUM = YR_Inspection.PROPERTYNUM 
JOIN YR_Branch
    ON YR_Property.BRANCHNUM = YR_Branch.BRANCHNUM
GROUP BY YR_Property.PROPERTYNUM
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add the branch number and the city for the branch, add `max` values for each to the query - like so:

```
SELECT YR_Property.PROPERTYNUM, 
       COUNT(YR_Inspection.PROPERTYNUM) AS Number_of_inspections,
       MAX(YR_Branch.BRANCHNUM) AS Branch_Number,
       MAX(YR_Branch.CITY) AS Branch_City
FROM YR_Property  
INNER JOIN YR_Inspection 
    ON YR_Property.PROPERTYNUM = YR_Inspection.PROPERTYNUM 
JOIN YR_Branch
    ON YR_Property.BRANCHNUM = YR_Branch.BRANCHNUM
GROUP BY YR_Property.PROPERTYNUM
```